# How to change admin panel in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want change html, css, javascript of django admin panel because default admin panel is very ugly. How to change html, css and javascript of django admin panel. Is it possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that I will suggest you to read this full documentation of Django for admin panel
[here is the link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/)

In short form you have to visit this link  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/
and here yo will find all the admin related template download it and in your main projects template folder create a folder name admin and in that paste and do the changes as you want but be very careful while working in these template and for customizing model you have to change you admin.py acc to your need you will find all the detail how to do it in first mentioned link

I would recommend you to please read the full documentation and then start implementing it